# Applying shell variable value on text files

Tags: shell, build

I am writing a script build.sh which will read from environment specific config file config..properties and apply to all config files and tar it. Please find sample code below.

--file config.dev.properties

`LOG_THRESHOLD=DEBUG`

--file build.sh

`# load properties file
     . ./config.dev.properties
    echo $LOG_THRESHOLD
    export LOG_THRESHOLD
    tar xvf package_dev.tar package`

-- file package/log4j.xml

`<log threshold="$LOG_THRESHOLD"/>`

--
Here I want when tar or cp command runs, log4j.xml is packaged with substituted value
`<log threshold="DEBUG"/>`

In my code, echo is returning DEBUG. but in tar it does not apply property value.

Am I missing something? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how... anything works. The shell has nothing to do with the contents of the files.

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -O -u '/log/@threshold' -v "foo" <<< '<log threshold="$LOG_THRESHOLD"/>'
<log threshold="foo"/>
```

So rename `log4j.xml` to `log4j.xml.tmpl`, use [XMLStartlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to generate the new `log4j.xml` (hint: redirection), and then tell tar to exclude the template file.

Comment: property may be applied to xml, text, another property file. XMLStarlet looks to be xml specific. My mchine does not have this utility.